# Preferred way to bind path in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want a simple paging control that updates the url, what is the ideal way to do this in angularjs?

ie:

http://www.site.com/widget/#/which/4

```
<a> Next </a>
```

For this, when Next link is clicked i want to update the url (and navigate to):
http://www.site.com/widget/#/which/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It pretty simple just use below line

```
   var pageIndex = $routeParams.pageNo
    var newpageIndex = parseInt(pageIndex) + 1;
    var url = '/which/' + newpageIndex
    $location.path(url);
```

Answer (score 2):

Any way that works, is easy to understand, and is maintainable is fine.

That said, you can just create links like so:

```html
<a href="#/which/5">5</a>
```

presuming you have some route like so:

```js
$routeProvider.when('which/:pageNo', {
    controller: 'MyCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'sometemplate.html'
});
```